# How do I identify which factor levels do not significantly differ during within group comparisons using emmeans()?

Tags: logistic, interaction, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, lsmeans

I am currently trying to look at how the likelihood of reaching a particular insect life-stage (in this example 1st instar) is influenced by both temperature (factor: 5 levels - 20, 23, 26, 29, 32 degrees Celsius) and species (factor: 2 levels - HA and AP) using a logistic regression model as below:

```
eggmodelA <- glm(cbind(No.hatched,No.eggs.added-No.hatched) ~ Temperature * Species, data=eggto1st.1, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

A likelihood ratio test revealed the interaction to be significant:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: cbind(No.hatched, No.eggs.added - No.hatched) ~ Temperature * 
    Species
Model 2: cbind(No.hatched, No.eggs.added - No.hatched) ~ Temperature + 
    Species
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1         0      0.000                          
2         4     40.007 -4  -40.007 4.315e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This has led me to use the emmeans() function in the package emmeans in order to complete both within species comparisons of temperature and within temperature comparisons of species. Below is the example for within species comparisons which gives the following output:

```
Within.species<-emmeans(eggmodelA, specs = pairwise ~ Temperature|Species)

$emmeans
Species = AP:
 Temperature  emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 20           0.6665 0.282 Inf    0.1133     1.220
 23           2.0314 0.376 Inf    1.2944     2.768
 26          -0.1297 0.170 Inf   -0.4629     0.204
 29           0.3238 0.159 Inf    0.0118     0.636
 32          -0.7361 0.161 Inf   -1.0518    -0.420

Species = HA:
 Temperature  emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 20           1.4088 0.336 Inf    0.7495     2.068
 23           0.9361 0.264 Inf    0.4190     1.453
 26           1.0116 0.176 Inf    0.6666     1.357
 29           0.0108 0.147 Inf   -0.2774     0.299
 32          -1.3157 0.170 Inf   -1.6484    -0.983

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
Species = AP:
 contrast estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 20 - 23   -1.3650 0.470 Inf -2.903  0.0303 
 20 - 26    0.7962 0.329 Inf  2.416  0.1109 
 20 - 29    0.3427 0.324 Inf  1.058  0.8282 
 20 - 32    1.4026 0.325 Inf  4.316  0.0002 
 23 - 26    2.1611 0.413 Inf  5.237  <.0001 
 23 - 29    1.7076 0.408 Inf  4.182  0.0003 
 23 - 32    2.7675 0.409 Inf  6.765  <.0001 
 26 - 29   -0.4535 0.233 Inf -1.947  0.2924 
 26 - 32    0.6064 0.234 Inf  2.589  0.0723 
 29 - 32    1.0599 0.226 Inf  4.680  <.0001 

Species = HA:
 contrast estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 20 - 23    0.4727 0.427 Inf  1.106  0.8036 
 20 - 26    0.3972 0.380 Inf  1.046  0.8338 
 20 - 29    1.3980 0.367 Inf  3.808  0.0013 
 20 - 32    2.7244 0.377 Inf  7.231  <.0001 
 23 - 26   -0.0755 0.317 Inf -0.238  0.9993 
 23 - 29    0.9253 0.302 Inf  3.063  0.0186 
 23 - 32    2.2518 0.314 Inf  7.177  <.0001 
 26 - 29    1.0008 0.229 Inf  4.363  0.0001 
 26 - 32    2.3273 0.245 Inf  9.516  <.0001 
 29 - 32    1.3265 0.225 Inf  5.906  <.0001 

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates
```

I have also used the following code to plot the results of this model:

```
emmip(eggmodelA, Species ~ Temperature, type = "response", xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Predicted probability of reaching 1st instar from 
      egg (± 95% confidence intervals)", CI = TRUE)
```

Would anyone be able to help me with the following questions:

1. How do I add letters to the emmeans$contrasts section to signify, within species, which temperatures did not differ significantly in regards to the likelihood of an individual reaching the 1st instar?
2. Is there any way I can add the letters from pairwise comparisons within factors to the plot of my model in R or do I have to do this separately outside of R? If possible I would also like to add some form of indicator on the graph for each temperature detailing if the two species differ significantly or not.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a coding/software implementation question rather than a statistical question, so it will probably be closed on this site according to the [site policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You'll probably be better off asking this type of question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You might try `multcomp::cld(Within.species$emmeans)` for Q1.

Comment: @Russ Lenth Unfortunately, when I try this I get the following error [Error in UseMethod("cld") : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "emmGrid"]